# langchain does not output results to the linux terminal

Tags: python, langchain

I'm new to langchain. I am using Manjaro Linux, Python, and standard Linux terminal.
After typing in the Python code presented on the video, there is no output from a query.

I have tried a couple a videos with the same result.
Here is the code from one of the videos that does not produce any thing to standard out.
What am I missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 
# see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLf90ipMzfE

import langchain
import PyPDF2
import os

from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from langchain.embeddings.openai  import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import ElasticVectorSearch, Pinecone, Weaviate, FAISS

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "sk-mykey-......"

# Location of the pdf file
reader = PdfReader('mypath/2023_GPT4All_Technical_Report.pdf')

# read date form the file and put them into a variable called raw_text
raw_text = ''
for i, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
     text = page.extract_text()
     if text:
         raw_text += text

raw_text[:100]

# We need to split the text that we read into smaller chunks 
# so that during the information retrieval we don't hit the token limit

text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
        separator = "\n",
        chunk_size = 1000,
        chunk_overlap = 200,
        length_function = len,
)
texts = text_splitter.split_text(raw_text)

# Next download "embedding from openAI
# embedding is a list of numbers, which are used to measure distances between 
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
docsearch = FAISS.from_texts(texts, embeddings)

# import question/answer chain
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.llms import OpenAI

# You can use other models, see 9:05 in video
chain = load_qa_chain(OpenAI(), chain_type="stuff")

# query
query = "who are the authors of the article?"
docs  = docsearch.similarity_search(query) 
chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query)

query = "what was the cost of training the GPT4all model?"
docs  = docsearch.similarity_search(query)
chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query)
```

Comment: the differences between a Notebook and terminal are clear to you? `chain.run` does return something, so what about `print(chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query))`

Answer (score 1):

```
 chain = load_qa_chain(OpenAI(), chain_type="stuff",verbose=True)
```

[Debugging chains](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/chains/how_to/debugging#:%7E:text=Setting%20verbose%20to%20True%20will,while%20it%20is%20being%20ran.)

> It can be hard to debug a Chain object solely from its output as most
> Chain objects involve a fair amount of input prompt preprocessing and
> LLM output post-processing.
>
> Setting verbose to True will print out some internal states of the
> Chain object while it is being ran.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your last line

```py
# query
query = "who are the authors of the article?"
docs  = docsearch.similarity_search(query) 
print(chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query))
```